# uploadTask method not working URLSession Swift 3

Tags: php, swift, xcode, urlsession

I wanna send a image to a server with the uploadTask method of URLSession class, I have the following function for upload image, but I can't read nothing on the php file.

```
@IBAction func uploadImage(_ sender: Any) {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    let url = URL(string: "http://www.localhost.com/destiny.php")!
    let file: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "colors", withExtension:"jpg")!

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("image/jpeg", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, fromFile: file) {
        (data: Data?, res: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        defer {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            }
        }
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        if data != nil{
            let strData = String(data:data!, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8)
            print(strData!)
        }
        let code = (res as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode
        print(code)
        if code != 201 {
            print(HTTPURLResponse.localizedString(forStatusCode: code))
            return
        }
        print("Uploaded!")
    }
    task.resume()
 }
```

The php file contains the following code:

```
print_r($_POST)
print_r($_FILES)
```

My output app:

```
Array()
Array()
200
no error
```

I hope can you help me to find what is wrong.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this adding the headers for PHP interpretation.